# Validate angular-formly form definition

Tags: angularjs, json, validation, angular-formly

I am working in an application where the user can provide a JSON formly form definition that is saved in the DB. Eventually, that definition will be used to generate a form.

I need to validate that JSON definition before saving it into the DB, something like what API-check does underneath.

Does angular-formly have something to do that or should I create my own validator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see it at http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/validators

Example with JSON:

```
 {
        "key": "test",
        "className": "flex-gt-xs-100 flex",
        "type": "input",
        "templateOptions": {
            "required": true
        },
        "validation": {
            "messages": {
                "required": "function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {return scope.to.label + ' is required';}"
            }
        }
    }
```

But JSON don't understand function. So, you need write code to do that

```
$http.get('test.json').success(function(array)
        {
           var jsonTransformed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array), function (key, value) {
               if (value && (typeof value === 'string') && value.indexOf("function") === 0) {
                   var jsFunc;
                   eval("jsFunc = " + value);
                   return jsFunc;
               }
               return value;
           });
           vm.fields = jsonTransformed;
        });
```

You should write validate function in controller and declare it in formly-field

Comment: But that is to validate the form itself. I am interested on the validation of the JSON definition. For instance, the user could type `"keys": "test"` instead of `"key":"test"`. **Angular-formly** detects that using **API-check**, but I need to do it programatically so I can give feedback to the user.